# A regex to match anything that doesn't start with a certain string

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm writing a mod_rewrite rule and would like a hand making it do what I want.

Basically I want the following cases to work:

```
request | Redirect to
---------------------
cheese  | /?page=cheese
abc123  | /?page=abc123
abc/def | /?page=abc/def
a/b/c/d | /?page=a/b/c/d
```

(Any alphanumeric plus . - / and _ redirected)

With two special cases:

```
request | Redirect to
------------------------
admin   | don't redirect
media   | don't redirect
```

With these two I don't want any sub directories etc to redirect either.

I've got as far as:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But this only satisfies the top two tests.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a separate **earlier** rule (as Kobi also suggested) and use the [`RewriteRule dash directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to prevent substitution.

> A dash indicates that no substitution
>   should be performed (the existing path
>   is passed through untouched). This is
>   used when a flag (see below) needs to
>   be applied without changing the path.

```
^index.php - [L]
^(admin|media) - [L]
^([A-Za-z0-9-_/\.]+)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

<strike>(I wasn't able to test this where I'm at right now, so you might need to edit this slightly - sorry .. but the idea should be clear)</strike>

Tested on Apache 2.2

---

EDIT: Was able to try this out now - needed to add the [L] to make it work.
EDIT2: Realized I didn't answer the full question, added rules for the rest of the stuff.

Comment: Cool - didn't know about the dash! Seems that visiting /admin/ doesn't go to the same place as /admin/index.php (It does without any rewrite rules...)

Comment: Where's /admin/ going? Do you have both index.html and index.php located under /admin? If you do, and index.html appears before index.php in Apache's DirectoryIndex config directive, that might be causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

If your version supports it, you can you use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!(?:admin|media)$)([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/$
```

Now, I'm no sys admin, but you can probably have an earlier rule to match `admin` and `media`, which is probably an easier idea.

Comment: Looks like you can, depending on the version: [Regex negative look-ahead is not working for mod_rewrite between different Apache versions](http://serverfault.com/q/120971/2454)

Comment: Oh, I also want to fail on `adminACB`, simply remove the `$` sign from the lookahead: `(?!admin|media)`

Comment: I like this, though I'm gonna go with the other answer as I think it's more maintainable as time goes on. Thanks a lot though!